# Alignment of rotated text divs css3

Tags: html, css

I have a few div's with different lengths of text:

```
<div id="first" class="myClass">Short</div>
<div id="second" class="myClass">Much more here</div>
...
```

Each of the div's is rotated 90 degrees, then I want them to line up vertically. Each div is a single line of text, no wrapping. I suspect I need to use transform-origin but how? Positioning is absolute and needs to be set relative to the right edge of the screen. They share a single css class.

UPDATE:
This is the right transformation:

```
-moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
-o-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
-webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
transform-origin: 100% 100%;
```

Comment: What does your CSS look like?

Comment: Make a parent container with `position:relative;`, that will enable you to style them appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Make a parent container with `position:relative;`, that will enable you to style them appropriately.

`position:absolute;` is a tricky badger that is hard to work with in **ONE** `div`.

Are you able to add some `HTML` to make this work?

And is there any reason you are adding `position:absolute;` to the `child` elements?

You could `position` the `parent element` with `absolute`, and make a `class` that would handle it with `float:right;`.

**Awaiting response - Please provide `CSS`**

Comment: The div's are placed absolutely because they need exact pixel distance from scrollTop=0.

Comment: I'm happy to help, but I need more code. Please provide `CSS`? It'd be lovely if you could provide a [JS Fiddle as well](http://jsfiddle.net). And if the `scrollTop=0` is defined, why didn't you include `Javascript` as well?